# how to run a specific jmx file using jmeter maven plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using Jmeter Maven plugin( http://jmeter.lazerycode.com) to trigger jmx files in my maven project.
Is there a way where I can specify which jmx file to run during run time instead of the plugin configuration testFilesDirectory, testFilesExcluded, testFilesIncluded etc in the pom.xml. 
In jmeter command line mode we can specify using -t.

jmeter -n -t mytest.jmx

Is there a similar option in the jmeter maven plugin

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this [`<testFilesIncluded>`](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Selecting-Tests-To-Run#specifying-testfilesincluded) tag?

If you define a [Maven Property](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-user-defined-properties-in-maven/) like

```
<properties>
    <jmeterScript>test1.jmx</jmeterScript>
</properties>
```

And refer it in the JMeter Maven plugin as:

```
<configuration>
    <testFilesIncluded>
        <jMeterTestFile>${jmeterScript}</jMeterTestFile>
    </testFilesIncluded>
</configuration>
```

You will be able to override the property value using `-D` command-line argument like:

```
mvn -DjmeterScript=someTest.jmx clean verify
```

or

```
mvn -DjmeterScript=someOtherTest clean verify
```

Full *pom.xml* file just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jmeterScript>test1.jmx</jmeterScript>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>${jmeterScript}</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

More information:

- [Introduction to the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)